# Is there a way to specify '--force' in chocolateyinstall.ps1?

Tags: powershell, package, package-managers, chocolatey, choco

I would like to be able to specify the --force argument within the chocolateyinstall.ps1 file. Currently, in that file I am invoking a batch file and try to append --force in the end but unsurprisingly it does not work.

Comment: Why are you doing this? What is your end goal?

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting [`$env:ChocolateyForce = 'true'`](https://docs.chocolatey.org/en-us/create/functions/#set-by-options-and-configuration) in `chocolateyInstall.ps1`, but normally this variable is meant for checking that `--force` was specified by the operator at the command line. It is generally used for modifying script behavior if `--force` was passed.

I don't know if changing the environment variable mid-script would have an effect or not on the `Install-Chocolatey*` cmdlets.